# Web page scraping using Beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract "automatically" some information (such as "Date", "Court", "Street"...) from a web page.
I want to use Beautiful soup to extract these information.

However, i have some problems using the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url =' https://www.licitor.com/annonce/08/45/23/vente-aux-encheres/un-pavillon-a-usage-d-habitation/epinay-sur-seine/seine-saint-denis/084523.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url) 
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soupe = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
page_soupe.findAll("article", {"class":"LegalAd"})
```

The result is

```
[<article class="LegalAd"></article>]
```

and does not show the all the content inside the 'article' tag.
[image]
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey @moby91 for me your code works fine and  it is showing data inside `article` tag or try with ` requests`  module

Comment: Thank you @BhavyaParikh, but the command does not return all the contant between the tag beginning and the tag end (as in the picutre).
Can you please give more details about "requests" module please ?

Comment: Try from this [post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/) or you can find topics from SO itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Here you go dude*

```
import xrzz
import re

url = 'https://www.licitor.com/annonce/08/45/23/vente-aux-encheres/un-pavillon-a-usage-d-habitation/epinay-sur-seine/seine-saint-denis/084523.html'
req = xrzz.http("GET", url=url,
    headers={
        "Host": "www.licitor.com",
        "Connection": "Close",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-J400F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.66 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }, tls=True).body()

print(re.findall("<h3>(.*?)</h3>", a.decode())[1])
```

> Output

Adjudication : 285 000 €

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7lzs.jpg)

> > **Using beautifulsoup**

```
import requests
import re
import bs4

url = 'https://www.licitor.com/annonce/08/45/23/vente-aux-encheres/un-pavillon-a-usage-d-habitation/epinay-sur-seine/seine-saint-denis/084523.html'
req= requests.get(url,
    headers={
        "Host": "www.licitor.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-J400F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.66 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    })

pg = bs4.BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'lxml')
page_soup = pg.findAll("article", {"class":"LegalAd"})
for i in page_soup:
    print(i.find("h3").text)
```

> > [**Output - (bs4)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsHAq.jpg)

Comment: thank you for your reply @Dedshit. 
I want the extract the price : 285 000 €
Any help ?

Comment: sure bro wait  let me do that

Comment: bro did you get that

Comment: Thanks bro, I get this error: 
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'TCP_KEEPIDLE'
Do you have an idea how to do this with Beautiful Soup ? 
Thanks again

Comment: let me do it bro

Comment: Done dude check that

Comment: NameError: name 'a' is not defined
@dedisht .. Thank you bro .. I get this error.. What is a ?

Comment: replace a.text to req.text in 12th line